# These terms are so foreign to me that they feel like unnecessary jargon; what do these terms mean, and are they relatively common?

Tags: definition, physics

No pun intended in the title. ;)

I am having trouble understanding this sentence on Wikipedia's page for [Unified Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_field_theory#Fields):

> Governed by a global event $\lambda$ under the universal topology, an operational environment is initiated by the scalar fields $\phi(\lambda) \in \{\phi ^+(\hat{x}, \lambda), \phi ^-(\hat{x}, \lambda)\}$ of a rank-$0$ tensor, a differentiable function of a complex variable in its domain at its zero derivative, where a scalar function $\phi ^+(\hat{x}, \lambda) \subset Y^+$ or $\phi ^-(\hat{x}, \lambda) \subset Y^-$ is characterized as a single magnitude with variable components of the respective coordinate sets $\hat{x}\{x^0, x^1, ...\}$ or $\hat{x}\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$

I've taken a graduate level GR class, so there are certain mathematical terms that I understand—but a few other terms seem absent from the internet outside of this article. From what I've found, the definition of terms often-used in a particular field (independent of how esoteric they may be) are available on the internet somewhere.

The terms I'm having trouble defining are:

1. global event (I know what an *event* is, but what is a **global** event?)
2. universal topology
3. operational environment

I know that this is mathematics/physics above me, but the difficulty I'm having finding these terms is surprising. What is their definition and are they commonly used terms?

Comment: That particular section stands out in the wiki page due to its lack of references and hyperlinks. Checking the history shows that it was added and revised by a single author with only a numeric IP address.

Comment: Maybe it's Alan Sokal again?